# Amazon Redshift: How to get hexadecimal code point of each character in a string to every row?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want to get code point of each character to check whether a string contains any character whose code point is larger than 0xFFFF.

For instance, I have a string 'BIGBANG'. I want to get the result as below:

```
to_hex
------
    42  -- B
    49  -- I
    47  -- G
    42  -- B
    41  -- A
    4e  -- N
    47  -- G
```

In Postgres 9.x I can simply run this query:

```
SELECT TO_HEX(ASCII(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('BIGBANG', '')));
```

But ASCII and REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE functions are not supported by Redshift.
How should I do in Redshift to get the same result?